# HashMap;I want the user to insert a int & the string will print

Tags: java, hashmap

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FIftyStates {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<Integer, String> FiftyStates = new HashMap <Integer, String>();
    //ad values in the map
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.Println(FiftyStates.get(scan.nextInt()));
    FiftyStates.put(1, "Delaware");    
    FiftyStates.put(2,"Pennsylvania");
    FiftyStates.put(3,"New Jersey");
    FiftyStates.put(4,"Georgia");
    FiftyStates.put(5,"Connecticut");
    FiftyStates.put(6,"Massachusetts" );
    FiftyStates.put(7,"Maryland");
    FiftyStates.put(8,"South Carolina");
    FiftyStates.put(9,"New Hampshire");
    FiftyStates.put(10,"Virginia");
    FiftyStates.put(11,"New York");
    FiftyStates.put(12,"North Carolina");
    FiftyStates.put(13,"Rhode Island");
    FiftyStates.put(14,"Vermont");
    FiftyStates.put(15,"Kentucky");
    FiftyStates.put(16,"Tennessee");
    FiftyStates.put(17,"Ohio");
    FiftyStates.put(18,"Louisiana");
    FiftyStates.put(19,"Indiana");
    FiftyStates.put(20,"Mississippi");
    FiftyStates.put(21,"Illinois");
    FiftyStates.put(22,"Alabama");
    FiftyStates.put(23,"Maine");
    FiftyStates.put(24,"Missouri");
    FiftyStates.put(25,"Arkansas");
    FiftyStates.put(26,"Michagan");
    FiftyStates.put(27,"Florida");
    FiftyStates.put(28,"Texas");
    FiftyStates.put(29,"Iowa");
    FiftyStates.put(30,"Wisconsin");
    FiftyStates.put(31,"California");
    FiftyStates.put(32,"Minnesota");
    FiftyStates.put(33,"Oregon");
    FiftyStates.put(34,"Kansas");
    FiftyStates.put(35,"West Virginia");
    FiftyStates.put(36,"Nevada");
    FiftyStates.put(37,"Nebraska");
    FiftyStates.put(38,"Colorado");
    FiftyStates.put(39,"North Dakota");
    FiftyStates.put(40,"South Dakota");
    FiftyStates.put(41,"Montana");
    FiftyStates.put(42,"Washington");
    FiftyStates.put(43,"Idaho");
    FiftyStates.put(44,"Wyoming");
    FiftyStates.put(45,"Utah");
    FiftyStates.put(46,"Oklahoma");
    FiftyStates.put(47,"New Mexico");
    FiftyStates.put(48,"Arizona");
    FiftyStates.put(49,"Alaska");
    FiftyStates.put(50,"Hawaii");   
}
```

}

Comment: I want the user to input a int (1-50) & the string prints, hope that makes sense.

Comment: refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920135/printing-hashmap-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by reversing your Map.
See the code below.

```
HashMap<Integer, String> FiftyStates = new HashMap <Integer, String>();
FiftyStates.put(1,"Delaware");
FiftyStates.put(2,"Pennsylvania");
...
...
...
...
FiftyStates.put(49,"Alaska");
FiftyStates.put(50,"Hawaii");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.Println(FiftyStates.get(scan.nextInt()));
```

Don't forget to close out the scanner.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it now & let you know.

Comment: If it works please don't forget to close the question out by marking this as an answer ... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: 1
null
this is what I get in the console when I type in a int

Comment: @Sal Can you please update your code in the question. It works perfectly for me.

Comment: Your problem is you do it before System.out.Println(FiftyStates.get(scan.nextInt())); you fill out the map... move this to the last line of program.. like i have it ...