# How can I display every class objects from Hashmap?

Tags: java

I have little problem displaying the contents of my hashmap.

```
public ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Student> StudentList 
                        = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

'Student' is a class with two string fields(first name, name), and addition method to return the name (get_name).

But my question is how can I display or it is possible to display names with keys about students in HashMap ?
I tried something like that, but only for one filed.

```
for(Student i : StudentList.values()) {
    System.out.println(i.get_name());
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920135/printing-hashmap-in-java

Comment: By the way, according to Java style conventions, method names and variable names start with a lowercase letter and use camel case, like `getName` and `studentList`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`entrySet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#entrySet--).

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer, Student> entry: StudentList.entrySet()){
   System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Or [`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-).

```
StudentList.forEach((key,value)->System.out.println(key + ": " + value));
```